ONVIF C# GetProfiles response 400 Bad Request
I wrote code try to do snapshot.
It works fine when I tested it with happytimesoft camera server.
When I tried to get real camera's media Profile, it response (400)Bad Request.
Then I found the uri I use to call GetProfile API looks not right.
I use this lib:
https://github.com/lu1770/onvif-client
Here is my main code
_deviceAgent = new DeviceAgent(cameraIP_textBox.Text, userName_textBox.Text, password_textBox.Text);
            _mediaAgent = new MediaAgent(_deviceAgent);

            
            var profiles = _mediaAgent.GetProfiles();
            _profileToken = profiles[0].token;

So I pull the nuget lib code and ref it to my project.
Then found out after excuted GetServices function, I'll get a map of service and it's XAddr.
And all service's XAddr are the same.
Here is the device map xaddr
enter image description here
My camera is VIGI C540V V1.
I found the camera could successfully connection with rstp.
And the device interface guidence shows the XAddr is right.
The device work fine with tp-link VIGI NVR application.
I use ODM to test the device. ODM could find the device, but can't show it's live video.
Can anybody help me with this problem? What could be the cause of this problem?
